# java.exe always point to the path of JRE but not JDK

Tags: environment-variables, java

I have both jdk and jre installed on my windows 7.

I have set the JAVA_HOME to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23
```

I have add

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin
```

to PATH.

but the java.exe still pointing to my jre dir, which is

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin
```

since when I run

```
java.exe -server
```

it complains

```
Error: no `server' JVM at `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll'.
```

can anyone tell me what else do I need to set?

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, did you restart the shell after changing the environment variables?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

since you are on windows, java doesn't work like that.
there is a java.exe in some windows directory (%windir% system32 for you)

This java.exe actually looks in the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`

PATH won't help ya! Since I tend to get lazy I delete the JRE and create a `junction` to the JDK instead.

Comment: the java.exe looks in the registry? Ya sure? I mean, java.exe is not supposed to do that...

Comment: @panny, I am not sure I understand that - not supposed by whom. Any windows process can lookup the registry. Some keys (or even hives) of the registry might be restricted to some processes/users but this is beyond the point.

Comment: @bestsss I just want to know about junction what is it all about ?

Comment: @anasanjaria, it's a Windows utility that mimic *nix symlinks: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Just remove java.exe from %windir%\system32

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 64bit operating system, it will try to use the 64bit jre that is preinstalled on windows 7.   You can try using add/remove programs to remove the 64bit jre.  I've had this problem several times and I've always fixed it by removing the 64bit jre.

Comment: on 64 bit OS, there is only 64bit -server JVM

Answer (score 0):

Right click MY Computer> properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables >

Search for Path..

Remove the exisiting path and then add yours..

take care of the semi colon

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by 'take care of the semi colon'?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your JRE/bin directory is not included in your path.  the first instance of java.exe found while searching your path will be the one that is executed.  if you've added your JDK to the path after the JRE then the JRE will always be picked.

you can also explicitly specify the full path to java.exe when invoking java. this will ensure that you always know what java jre/jdk you are invoking.