# Path resolution without PATH variable

Tags: java

I installed the latest JDK 1.6.0_25 on my Windows 7 64-bit machine. I then tried "java -version" on the command prompt, without editing the path variable. It worked, so I assumed that the installation added the new path to the environment.

But when I looked at the path variable through the Advanced System Settings tab, there was no sign of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\" or anything equivalent to it.

How is the path getting resolved?

Comment: the question has been asked a few times on stackoverflow actually.

Comment: @bestsss, Please provide references.

Comment: google usually does the trick, for instance: http://www.google.com/search?q=+site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE%5cSOFTWARE%5cJavaSoft%22+bestsss (and lazy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250806/java-exe-always-point-to-the-path-of-jre-but-not-jdk )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Windows Server 2003, Vista, or Windows 7, you can try the `where` command:

`C:\>where java`

For anyone using Linux, the `where` equivalent is `whereis`.

Comment: That clears it up! java.exe appears to be present in C:\Windows\System32 as well. Although that is a different version 1.6.0_17

Comment: that's more or less incorrect: java is in system directory and in the registry it say where the active version is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment

Answer (score 1):

it is kept in the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
Java install a small exe in the system folder that looks up the keep and redirects there, so no PATH necessary.

Linux version usually uses update-alternatives (depends on the distribution, of course)